# PHP One To Many

Tags: php

I Have 2 Table. 1 Table Questions, 1 Table Answers.

I Need 1 Questions in 4 Answers.

Because I create a web application for students.

[image: QUESTIONS MYSQL]

[image: ANSWERS MYSQL]

I want this JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
     "question": "Türkiye'nin Başkenti Neresidir?",
      "answers": [
        {
         "id": "1",
          "answer": "Ankara",
          "query": "1"
        },
        {
         "id": "2",
          "answer": "Istanbul",
          "query": "0"
        }
      ]
   }
],
```

Postman

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "question": "Türkiye'nin Başkenti Neresidir?",
        "answers": {
            "id": "1",
            "answer": "Ankara",
            "query": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "question": "Türkiye'nin Başkenti Neresidir?",
        "answers": {
            "id": "2",
            "answer": "İstanbul",
            "query": "0"
        }
    },
]
```

PHP Code

```
public function GetQuestions($AppID){
          $QuestionArray = [];
          $Select = $this -> DBConnect -> prepare("SELECT questions.id, questions.question, answers.id AS answerid, answers.answer AS answer,answers.query AS query FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.questionid WHERE active = 1 AND appid = ".$AppID);
            $Select -> execute();
            $Questions = $Select -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             foreach($Questions as $Item){
              $QuestionArray[] = Array(
               'id' => $Item['id'],
               'question' => $Item['question'],
               'answers' => Array(
                  'id' => $Item['answerid'],
                  'answer' => $Item['answer'],
                   'query' => $Item['query']
                  )
               );
           }
        return $JSON = json_encode($QuestionArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the content of **$Questions** in well format.

Comment: And what does that existing code do? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this procedure.

```
public function GetQuestions($AppID)
{
    $QuestionArray = [];
    $Select = $this->DBConnect->prepare('SELECT questions.id, questions.question, answers.id AS answerid, answers.answer AS answer,answers.query AS query FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.questionid WHERE active = 1 AND appid = '.$AppID);
    $Select->execute();
    $Questions = $Select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($Questions as $Item) {
        if (!array_key_exists($Item['id'], $QuestionArray)) {
            $QuestionArray[$Item['id']] = array(
            'id' => $Item['id'],
            'question' => $Item['question'],
            'answers' => array(),
           );
        }
        $QuestionArray[$Item['id']]['answers'][] = array(
         'id' => $Item['answerid'],
         'answer' => $Item['answer'],
         'query' => $Item['query'],
      );
    }

    return $JSON = json_encode($QuestionArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, you can reference and update with your cases.

1. GetQuestions

   ```
   public function GetQuestions($appID) {
      // TODO 
      // $quest_result = Get form DB;
      foreach ($quest_result as $quest) {
           $quest_response[id]      = $quest[id]; 
           $quest_response[quest]   = $quest[question]; 
           $quest_response[answers] = getAnswerByQuestId ($quest[id]);
      }
      return $quest_response;
   }
   ```
2. getAnswerByQuestId

   ```
   public function getAnswerByQuestId(questionID) {
       // TODO 
       // $array_answer = Get form DB;

       return $array_answer;

       // ex: 
       // return array_answer[
       //  "id": "1",
       //  "answer": "Ankara",
       // "query": "1"
       //] 
   }
   ```